# How to add parameters to Oledb Source in ssis programmatically

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis

I am creating an ssis package which contains an OLE DB Source.

The OLE DB Source component execute SP is:

```
EXEC [dbo].[USP_GetCustomerEtlSourceDetailRecordSet] @OrganizationName=?,@SourceRunID=?
```

How do I create parameters using C# code to pass to the above SP?

I tried this, and it's not working, how do I map "@OrganizationName" parameter which is **Project Parameter**?

```
Guid variableGuid = new Guid(proj.Parameters["OrganizationName"].ID);
Guid SourceRunID = new Guid(Parent_ETLSourceRunId.ID);
String Parent_ETLSourceRunId1 = @"""@OrganizationName"",{" + variableGuid.ToString().ToUpper() + @"}" + ";" + @"""@SourceRunID"",{" + SourceRunID.ToString().ToUpper() + @"};""";
srcDesignTime.SetComponentProperty("ParameterMapping", Parent_ETLSourceRunId1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what l did that to pass parameters to stored procedure.  Dragged Execute SQL task to the designer pane, below is the SQL Query, l have used.
[image: SQL Query]

Next step is to go to the 'Parameter Mapping' section of the task.  I clicked on the 'Add' button, in the variable column there is a pull down list, of all the available variables.
[image: Select variable from list]

Note the variable value is being passed into the stored proceedure so the direction is 'input'.

These two articles should give you some more information 
[Mapping parameters and results sets](http://www.programmersedge.com/post/2013/03/05/ssis-execute-sql-task-mapping-parameters-and-result-sets.aspx#.U6RJK_ldXrk)
[Passing parameters using script task](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/passing-variables-to-and-from-an-ssis-task/)